# vuejs2 - how to create event buses for single file component hierarchies

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've found a solution by LinusBorg [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/eventhub-with-vueify/1375/4), that registers a bus globally in any Vue instance. Is there a way to define this in a component hierarchy instead, so that I can create multiple scoped busses? Basically, if I had multiple "root"-level components with some children, an event bus should be instanciated for the "root"-level component and it's children, rather than all Vue instances.

I can't use the simple `$emit` and `$on`, because the hierarchy isn't restricted to plain `parent-child` communication. So events have to be passed over multiple levels.

Comment: If you just want to  emit back to a parent then you can emit directly to it using: `this.$parent.$emit`, or use `this.$emit` and listen for the event directly on the component.

Comment: The hierarchy has multiple components, and not just direct child -> parent communication is required. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a js file like `eventBus.js`, and just export a vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const bus = new Vue()
export default bus
```

then you can import the event bus in your .vue file

```
import bus from 'path/to/eventBus'

...

bus.$on('foo', ...)
```

---

Update my answer from the discussion in comments:

Since a event name is just a string, you can add a prefix/namespace to the event, like `bus.$emit('domain.foo')` or `bus.$emit('domain/foo')`.

If you feel your application becomes more and more complex, just go for vuex.

Comment: How would I use this in a child component? Importing the bus would create a new instance. So how would I be able to bind the bus to the component hierarchy?

Comment: @Johannes No, the instance will only be created once. All your imported `bus` is the same instance

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get this. If `eventBus.js` only creates the instance once, what's the difference of using LinusBorg's solution, where I bind an instance to the `Vue` prototype? What I'm up to is to create differently scoped busses (let's say we have a scoped bus for a grid-component, another one for chat component, etc.)

Comment: Oops I misunderstood your question. The simplest solution is to add a prefix (namespace) to the event name. Or, just create several Vue instances, and import the corresponding one

Comment: You can also import the bus from root components, and pass it down via props. But if your application becomes that complex, maybe it's time to use Vuex

Comment: I was looking for an incomplex and lightweight solution, which is why I opted for emit and on in the first place.

Comment: I think creating more than 1 event bus is just adding unnecessary complexity to the application. Event name is just a string, so you can add namespace to it. `bus.$emit('domain.foo')` or if you prefer slash `bus.$emit('domain/foo')`

Comment: Alright, so I guess my question didn't make much sense in the first place. Anyhow, this concludes my questions then. Thanks!